# Как найти поля, в которых отличается только порядок слов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Добрый день!

В БД PostgreSQL в таблицах есть поля с названиями организаций. Нужно найти одинаковые без учета порядка слов. Разделитель - один или несколько пробелов.

Примеры:
'ЭКОФЛОН ЗАО НПК' = 'ЭКОФЛОН  НПК ЗАО';
'ГАРАНТ НПО ЗАО' = 'ГАРАНТ ЗАО НПО'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать?

Заранее благодарна!

Comment: Я бы на языке программирования генерировал все возможные варианты строки и делал поиск по этим вариантам, но возможно в `postgresql` есть какой-то другой хитрый способ.

Comment: Можно используя case when и coalesce сделать "упорядоченый" столбец, и сгрупировать по нему.

Comment: типа coalesce(case when a1 < a2 and a1 <a3 then a1 end,  case when a2 < a1 and a2 <a3 then a2 end,  case when a3 < a1 and a3 <a2 then a3 end) + ' ' + coalesce ... + ' ' + coalesce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Преобразуем строки в массивы, используя функцию `regexp_split_to_array`
2. Используем операторы "содержит" (`@>`) и "содержится в" (`<@`) для определения полного совпадения массивов (без учета порядка элементов). Если A содержит B и A содержится в B - то массивы полностью идентичны.

Запрос для склейки подобных записей из таблицы wtest такой:

```
with Q as (
select a.*,regexp_split_to_array(txt,' +') arr
  from wtest a
)
select * from Q a, Q b
 where a.arr <@ b.arr and a.arr @> b.arr and a.id!=b.id
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/09f04/2)

Вариант 2. Так же преобразуем в массив слов, сортируем его и собираем обратно в строку. Отсортированные строки можно сравнивать или например отсортировать по ним выборку, что бы подобные строки оказались рядом:

```
select a.*,
       array_to_string(array(select unnest(regexp_split_to_array(txt,' +')) AS x order by x),' ') srt
  from wtest a
 order by srt
```

Comment: Спасибо за оба варианта.

Comment: Большое спасибо, @Mike !
Нужно было найти соответствие двух таблиц по названиям, теперь я смогу это сделать!