# Разбить строку на подстроки, число подстрок не известно, одну запись превратить во множество записей

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

Есть таблица с одним строковым полем неопределённой длины, `BLOB`, в строке текст.
Нужно каждую строку разбить на слова, разделённые к примеру пробелом, и в новую таблицу записать только полученные слова.

Например, строку "Маша ела кашу" записать в:

```
Маша
ела 
кашу
```

Длина строки и число слов в строке на момент начала обработки неизвестна.

Что можно использовать, рекурсию или достаточно средств SQL?

В каких БД возможно решить задачу? В MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL?

Так как если решения для MySQL нет, но есть в других БД, то может быть выгоднее перезалить данные в иную базу и решить там.

Вот [похожее решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681129/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-pl-sql), но по числу символов, а не по символу разделителю.

Comment: Можно в любой БД в которой есть строковые функции (что бы можно было искать пробелы и вырезать куски строк) с использованием опорной таблицы, как например тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569174/194569  (Тут задача немного другая, но суть, думаю, понятна, опорная таблица используется для генерации возможных смещений или номеров слов (для SUBSTRING_INDEX)) А решения с рекурсией обычно более громоздки и более медленны.

Comment: А, вот даже разбиение по пробелам нашел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537044/194569

Comment: Тут вопрос скорее в наличии более удобных функций для работы со строками. вроде регулярок в oracle, совместно с connect by и почти готовых функций специально для этих целей в postgresql (там ни рекурсия ни таблица не нужны, наверняка найдется готовая функция разбиение с разворачиванием в строки)

Comment: Смущает, что поле `blob`, не уверен что полочится в Оракле разобрать его без хранимых процедур

Comment: Вот вариант для postgresql https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549007/194569  (см. вариант 2, причем он делает гораздо больше чем просто разбор)

Answer (score 2):

В любом брэнде БД есть какое-то решение, так что репликация вряд ли нужна.

Вот один из простых вариантов для Oracle:

```sql
create table t1 as select 'Маша ела кашу' sentence from dual
/
create table t2 (word varchar2 (32));
/
insert into t2  
    select t.column_value
    from t1, table (Tokenizer (sentence, ' ').tokens) t;

select * from t2;

WORD
------------------------
Маша                
ела                  
кашу
```

Реализацию функций токенизации предложил в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128223/217579).

---

**PS** Под `BLOB` в вопросе вероятно имелось ввиду - `CLOB`. Если не так, то поможет:

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (blob_value, len, offset)
```