# Преобразовать строку с диапазонами числовых значений в строку отдельных чисел с запятой как разделителем

Tags: парсер, oracle, plsql

Допустим, есть символьная строка: `1-3,4,9,11-15`.

Есть ли простой путь преобразовать её в строку отдельных чисел с запятой как разделителем в PL/SQL?

Можно найти множество решений, разбить строку по разделителю на отдельные значения, а также, собрать строку из отдельных значений. А как быть, если в строке встречаются диапазоны значений?

То есть, конечный результат хотелось бы видеть так: `1,2,3,4,9,11,12,13,14,15`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Convert string with groups of numbers to a comma separated string with single numbers in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63187755) от участника [@Weltraumfahrer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10255589/weltraumfahrer)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63187755

Comment: Да в принципе должно несложно решаться в CTE. Сперва разобрать на группы по запятой, потом для элементов с тире в рекурсивном CTE сгенерять отдельные значения.

Comment: @Akina Ну да, два стандартных решения собрать в одно. Оба ответивших примерно так и сделали.

Comment: @Akina Да, ещё, в PL/SQL понятия CTE нет, хотя решается примерно также.

Answer (score 2):

Взял за основу [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128223/217579) (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=259a0786f769ccefe9e9a6550d5bb9a0)). Унаследовал с новым конструктором и одной вспомогательной функцией:

```
create or replace type TokenizerExt under Tokenizer (
    constructor function TokenizerExt (
        str varchar2, delimiter char:=',', spansign char:='-') return self as result,
    static function range (str varchar2, spansign char) return tokenList)
/
create or replace type body TokenizerExt as
    constructor function TokenizerExt (
        str varchar2, delimiter char:=',', spansign char:='-') return self as result is
        tmp tokenList := Tokenizer.split (str, delimiter);
    begin 
        self.tokens := tokenList (); --:= Tokenizer (str, delimiter).tokens; 
        for i in 1..tmp.count loop
            self.tokens := self.tokens multiset union TokenizerExt.range (tmp(i), spansign); 
        end loop;    
        return; 
    end;
    static function range (str varchar2, spansign char) return tokenList is
        ret tokenList := tokenList ();
        p int; 
    begin 
        if regexp_like (str, '^\d+'||spansign||'\d+$') then
            p := instr (str, spansign);
            for d in (substr (str, 1, p-1))..(substr (str, p+1)) loop
                ret.extend; ret(ret.last) := d; 
            end loop;
        else
           ret := tokenList (str);
        end if;
        return ret;
    end;
end;
/
```

Даст ожидаемый результат:

```
select TokenizerExt ('1-3,4,9,11-15').join() result from dual 
/

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------
1,2,3,4,9,11,12,13,14,15
```