# Создать функцию, превращающую одну CSV строку в таблицу, используя регулярное выражение для поиска разделителей

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Подскажите пожалуйста как переделать [следующий код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137629/5741205):

```
with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'string-1 , string-2 ; string-3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'single string' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^,;]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.error, '[^,;]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name;
```

в универсальную функцию, которая принимает в качестве параметров строку (пример: `'string--1, string-2 ; string-3 , string-4'`) и регулярное выражение, задающее поиск разделителя строк (пример: `'\s*[,;]\s*'`):

```
FUNCTION csvstr2tab(
    p_str      IN VARCHAR2,
    p_sep_re   IN VARCHAR2   DEFAULT '\s*[,;]\s*'
)
...
```

---

В качестве собственных попыток - вот функция, которая выполняет данную задачу, используя **фиксированный** разделитель строк (`','`):

```
create or replace type admin.strtable as table of varchar2(1000);
/

create or replace
function admin.str2tbl ( p_str in varchar2 ) return strtable
as
  l_str long default p_str || ',';
  l_n number;
    l_data strtable := strtable();
begin
  loop
    l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
    exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
    l_data.extend;
    l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
    l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
  end loop;
  return l_data;
end;
/
```

PS [sql<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38a5f044f92ec93fd09a601cd0b0e9d4)

---

**UPDATE:** я использовал абревиатуру CSV только лишь для того, чтобы показать, что я имею дело со строками, в которых находяться подстроки, разделенные разделителями. На самом деле входные строки совсем не обязательно являются "валидными" CSV.

Comment: Вот вчера нельзя было задть вопрос? Сегодня и завтра время ограниченно.

Comment: @0xdb, вчера эта задача не была приоритетной для меня, а сегодня - да ;)

Comment: Вот делал недавно с [польз. типом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128223/217579). Там ниже показано, как разбивать по регулярке.

Comment: @0xdb, и вся эта красота будет работать на Oracle 12.2 ?

Comment: А куда она денется? Конечно будет, там ничего нового нет.

Comment: @0xdb, буду рад увидеть ваш ответ на мой вопрос, когда у вас появится время на ответ ;)

Comment: Чё фигнёй-то маяться? [JSON_TABLE()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973)... а преобразовать CSV в валидный JSON - не проблема вроде.

Comment: @Akina, может оформите ответ с примером функции? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте воспроизводимый пример ниже (проверил на версии 12.2.0.1.0).

Подготовка схемы:

```
create table prjerr as
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'string-1 , string-2 ; string-3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'single string' from dual
/
create or replace type tokenList is table of varchar2 (32767)
/
```

Сама функция:

```
create or replace function csvstr2tab (
        str varchar2, delimiter char := '\s*[,;]\s*') return tokenList is
    pattern constant varchar2 (64) := '(.*?)(('||delimiter||')|($))';
    tokens tokenList := tokenList ();
    s varchar2 (96);
    c int := 0;
begin 
    <<split>> loop c := c + 1;  
        s := regexp_substr (str, pattern, 1, c, null, 1);
        exit split when s is null; 
        tokens.extend;
        tokens(tokens.last) := s;
    end loop;
    return tokens;
end csvstr2tab;
/
```

Запрос и результат:

```
select distinct name, project, t.column_value error
from prjerr p, csvstr2tab (p.error) t 
order by name
/
      NAME PROJE ERROR           
---------- ----- ----------------
       108 test  string-1        
       108 test  string-2        
       108 test  string-3        
       109 test2 single string
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115710/discussion-on-answer-by-0xdb-----csv---).

Comment: можете подсказать (в отдельном ответе) как можно расширить данную функция таким образом, чтобы она принимала дополнительный параметр `ignore_nulls`, который по умолчанию игнорировал бы входящие NULL значения, а если указать `ignore_nulls=>0`, тогда в результате присутствовали бы оригинальные строки со значением NULL? Или лучше все-таки задать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @MaxU То есть, вся строка с запятыми может быть null, я правильно понял?

Comment: да, все правильно - если расширить входные данные: `union all select 110, 'test3', NULL from dual`

Comment: @MaxU Вот так [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d652b1964f312afa018c0529c2447386)?

Comment: @0xdb, да, спасибо!! Это именно то, что нужно! Можете оформить это как отдельный ответ? ;)

Comment: @MaxU Рад был помочь! Не маловато ли для нового ответа? Всего то один if. Но я подумаю, как можно преподать новое условие. Сейчас всё равно на работе и время оформлять ответ нет.

Comment: @0xdb, по-моему, как раз для нового ответа, т.к. данный ответ отвечает на изначальный вопрос, а новый ответ будет отвечать на дополненный вопрос. PS я подожду, мне не к спеху ;)